# iOS simulator can't connect to localhost

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm running the iOS simulator on a windows machine to do xamarin development. But the simulator can't connect to localhost - not from my app, and not from Safari.

From a browser on my machine I can connect to http://localhost:56637/ or to http://127.0.0.1:56637/ and the site loads fine.

But Safari on the simulator gives me "could not connect to server" for both of these forms. I can connect to other sites on the web with no problems.

My understanding is that the phone uses the local computer's network connection, so firewalls shouldn't be an issue. What am I missing?

Comment: First, the simulator runs on the Mac, not the PC.  VS displays the UI on the PC using a remote connection.  Second, "localhost" on the simulator will make the **simulator connect to itself**.  Use the IP or FQDN of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that **iPhone Simulator** can not connect to `http://localhost:56637/` or `http://127.0.0.1:56637/`  , because the **iPhone Simulator** is remoted from Mac to PC , not in PC actually .

If need to use that adresss , **the solution** that is need to make the web server published in Mac .

In addition , another idea that you also can use the **IP** of pc to visit the web server .Such as `http://192.168.1.88:56637/` , `192.168.1.88` is the IP of pc . If ip is private ,keep PC and Mac in the same segment of network . Or using public ip (*FQDN*) not need to consider that .